# Using bitcount command in redis

Tags: redis, bitcount

I set a key to 0 and get the bitcount using the below command in redis

```
 set result 0
 bitcount result
```

I get the output to be 2 instead of 0.
When i set the result to any other number and print the bitcount I get the correct number of set bits with the addition of 2. Why is 2 by default added to the bitcount's result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `result` holds the character `"0"` which is the integer `48` in decimal, which is `110000` in binary.